# Need explanation for this command "chown -R apache.apache wp-content"

Tags: apache, webserver

Problem statement: Trying to set up a webserver and install a wordpress on it.while trying to install, came across this command  "apache.apache" .Wanted to know what this command does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`chown` is for changing the **owner**, in your case your are going to change the user and group owners of wp-content to `apache`, `apache`.

```
chown $user:$group $directoryname
```

and `-R` for recursive which means wp-content and all its files and sub directories

Please read the following guide that will help you to understand some linux basics that would be helpful in the future: [Linux User Management](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/36845/the-beginners-guide-to-managing-users-and-groups-in-linux/)

Comment: Could you please mark the question as answered then ?

Comment: hey Mostafa, in the above command "chown -R apache.apache wp-content". apache. apache is the user and the group  am i correct ? coz, my tutor used/executed the command apache.apache  NOT apache:apache . So the period and the : doesn't make a difference?

Comment: there is no difference except in some cases you may have a user called `rangesh.prasanna` , for me i would use `:` if there is a user has a dot in his name

Comment: thanks mostafa !! I know these are basics . I am figuring my way around unix and apache . thanks for taking the time to respond to my basic queries. I shall close this now :) !! happy friday